# Context prefixes not loading in JsonLdParser.Load

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf

I'm trying to load some basic json-ld content as a string, but I'm not able to see the namespace prefixes that should be included.

Given the following json-ld:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "image": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/image",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  },
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "foaf:homepage": "http://manu.sporny.org/",
  "image": "http://manu.sporny.org/images/manu.png"
}
```

I run this against the [dotnetrdf](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf) library:

```
void Main()
{   
    var targetPath = @"C:\Users\me\MinContext.json";
    var jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(targetPath);

    var parser = new JsonLdParser();
    var store = new TripleStore();
    parser.Load(store, new StringReader(jsonStr));
    
    var g = store.Graphs.FirstOrDefault();
    IUriNode rdfType = g.CreateUriNode("rdf:type");
    IUriNode home = g.CreateUriNode("foaf:homepage");
}
```

On the last line I get this `RdfException` message:

> The Namespace URI for the given Prefix 'foaf' is not known by the
> in-scope NamespaceMapper.  Did you forget to define a namespace for
> this prefix?

...and if you inspect the graph namespaces (g.NamespaceMap.Prefixes) you can see that it only contains three: rdf, rdfs and xsd.

So question: how do I get the foaf prefix and namespace to load correctly?

This is based on using NuGet package version 2.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefixes are not an inherent part of any RDF graph, they are just conventions and shortcuts so that you don't have to type the full IRI. A specific database software/implementation can have options for configuring namespaces/prefixes, but they are just for presentation.

In this case, `JsonLdParser` simply does not import any prefix from the source data into the graph. This is a perfectly valid behaviour, and I don't know if it can be changed. `Load` can also take `IRdfHandler`which seems to be able to do something with prefixes, but creating an implementation will most likely be more difficult than simply defining the namespace yourself:

```
g.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("foaf", new Uri("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"));
```

I'd argue this is actually the more correct option. The source document can specify `foaf:` to be absolutely anything, but you want *this* `foaf:` (the full meaning of a resource name comes from the IRI of its prefix, not from the prefix name itself).

The alternative to that is `g.CreateUriNode(new Uri("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage"))` which creates a completely equivalent node. Of course it is simpler to add the namespace instead of typing the full IRI every time – that's what namespaces are for.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed description.  So you're saying that I have to know the prefixes and Uris in advance or have some logic to parse the context before I begin creating the graph?

Comment: You should know them in advance. You rely on the full URIs, not on a particular prefix.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I was hoping it the read in would fully resolve all of the Uri's.  Anyway, thanks very much for your help.